# TypeError: debts.map is not a function only on chrome React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

so i have this code

```
export const Balance = () =>{
const {debts} = useContext(GlobalContext);

const amounts = debts.map(debt => debt.amount);
const total = amounts.reduce((acc, item) => (acc += item), 0).toFixed(2);
return (
        <div className="balance-container">
            <div>
            <h4>סכום כולל</h4>
            <h2><CountUp start={0} end={Number(total)} duration={2.5} separator=","></CountUp>&#8362;</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

the error that i get is :
TypeError: debts.map is not a function

and the application is crash.
the strange thing is that when i copy the url (my  local host and port) to firefox, or to chrome in mobile the application is running well...

what can be the problem?

Comment: Did you log `debts` before calling `map` to see what it contains in each case?

Comment: `debts` on console.log with chrome is an objact but on firefox its array

Comment: So then the real error is that the context is not returning the correct datatype. `map` is doing what we expect on an array, and what we expect on an object (breaking). I would redirect your debugging search to the `GlobalContext`.

Comment: this is the code there
 ```const initialState = {
  debts: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("debts")) || [],
};

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("debts", JSON.stringify(state.debts));
  });```

Comment: Can you edit the question and add that so its easier to read and all in one place?

Comment: My guess would be your `debts` in local storage got set to an object somehow in chrome, but in other browsers its using the fallback empty array `[]`.

Comment: so how can i set it to an array in chrome? there is anyway?

Comment: What I'm saying is I don't think this is a Chrome specific issue, I think Chrome just  happens to have some bad data stored in local storage. You could clear it, but the problem will most likely come back. Something had to store the bad data in the first place. That's what you should be looking for. Something dispatched an object instead of an array to your `AppReducer`.

Comment: If your application is small enough, you could make a runnable example on a sandbox or snippet, so that we can help further, otherwise I'd start checking places where you update the `AppReducer`. Try clearing local storage and see what makes the issue come back.

Comment: so i think i sloved it! i just clear the storage on chrome as you said and its work fine - the localstorage on chrome makes an array of objects like firefox did. 
thanks you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because `debts` is null or undefined. an idiomatic solution is to default that value to an empty array when you initialize it:

```
const debts = []
```

instead of (what you're probably doing now)

```
const debts = null
```

when you call .map on an empty array it will have no effect so it will be handled gracefully if the values have not been added yet.
When the debts array is populated with values, they will be rendered.

Comment: this is when i am initialize it: 

`const initialState = {
  debts: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("debts")) || [],
};`

the problem is that on chrome browser its error, but firefox works fine with the same code

Comment: If `debts` were null or undefined the error would be something like "`map` does not exist on `undefined`". But instead the error is "`map` is not a function". Which tells us that `debts` exists, but is not an array

Comment: `console.log(debts)` return me an object on chrome, and  array on firefox